# python reading file with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, string, numpy, input

Another newbie in python.

I am trying to read from file the following

> 000001 001,01 001,02 001,03 001,04 +83.44556 -4.42692396 +.0018912
> -1.625533 +.0006944 -85.36787 +367.192620 +369.0000 20180130_141607 CH 01 GN 1   128
>
> 000002 001,01 001,02 001,04 001,05 +54.27095 -.719790446
> +.0004728 -.2643017 +.0001736 +8.225120 +367.192620 +369.0000 20180130_141607 CH 02 GN 2   128

I tried the follwing command

```
Z0=np.genfromtxt('1X21_DD_WN20180130_1114.Data',comments='#','!','R'],
skip_header=100,skip_footer=2)
```

but the number 001,01 001,02 are returned as NAN.

I tried the

```
Z00=np.genfromtxt('1X21_DD_WN20180130_1114.Data',comments=
['#','!','R'],skip_header=100,skip_footer=2,delimiter=[' ',','])
```

But I get an error message (Cannt perform accumulate with flexible type)

Then I went to the following path

```
with open('1X21_DD_WN20180130_1114.Data', 'rb') as f:
    y=[[     line.replace(b',',b' ')    ] for line in f.readlines()[100:-3]]
```

which returns a list in y. But I do not know how to proceed with the split.

Now I am using the following expression

```
in_file=open('1X21_DD_WN20180130_1416.Data', 'rb')
readfile=in_file.readlines()[100:-3]
y2=np.zeros([17,1])
for line in readfile:
    y2=np.c_[y2,np.asarray(line.replace(b',',b' ').split())
    [0:17].astype(float)];

y2=y2[:,1:]
y2=y2.T
```

There must be a better way
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, with some trial and error, I come to this

```
with open('1X21_DD_WN20180130_1416.Data', 'rb') as f:
    y=np.asarray([     line.replace(b',',b' ').replace(b'*',b'0').replace(b'TX',b'0').replace(b'Resist.',b'0').replace(b'out',b'0').replace(b'of',b'0').replace(b'range',b'0').split()[0:17]    for line in f.readlines()[100:-3]]).astype(float)
```